# A simple HTML Anchor Link does not show-up as a link when sending a mail from Samsung galaxy S III

Tags: android

I have developed an android application in which I am sending a mail whose body text contains a link for downloading my application from Google play store.

This works fine for all other android devices except Samsung Galaxy S III. The issue that I am facing is when I am **sending a mail from Samsung Galaxy S III**, the **link in email** appears to be **normal text** instead.

It seems like it is a device specific problem. I have worked around for a solution, but I am unable to find it.

Why this happening only in case of Samsung galaxy S III?